# Generating C code from a Matlab-Simulink model for DSP C6748

Tags: embedded, dsp, programming, dac, matlab

I'm trying to generate C code from a Matlab-Simulink simple model (eg.: sine wave generator with a DAC at the output). This code must be executed with Code Composer Studio 
for TMS320C6748 DSP (Texas Instrument C6748). Specifically, for the development board OMAP-L138 ZOOM ™EVM DEVELOPMENT KIT.

For this, I am using the following versions:
Simulink (Version 7.7 - R2011a)
Embedded Coder (Version 6.0 - R2011a)
Code Composer Studio v3.3

I tried several options (with generic modules in Simulink and programming the C6748 timers, configuring a module "Target Preferences" with "OMAP_L138/C6748 EVM"...) but it isn't working.

Is it possible to implement this idea? Is there an example working?

Thanks

Comment: It is absolutely possible. I am working on the exact same concept only I am targetting a TMS320C64xx DSP and I do not have a generic dev board. You're going to need to provide a little more information than "it isn't working." As for an example working, I have not found much. If you're interested in some of the test cases I've done I would be happy to point you in the right direction. However, I haven't gotten anything too advanced working yet since I'm struggling with converting my floatingp algorithm to fixedp algorithm since the C64xx does not support floatingp, yours does though.

Comment: Thanks @JGord! I tried several options, the two most productive:

1.- A demo titled "Parametric Audio Equalizer", but I get this error: "No suitable replacement found for processor 'OMAPL138' set currently in the Target Preferences block. Delete the current Target Preferences block and add a new one".

Comment: 2.- A simple model with a sine wave generator and a generic DAC at the output. I compiled with a "Generic Real-Time Target", generating ert_main.c with the functions rt_OneStep(), Model_initialize(), Model_terminate().
I created a new project with Code Composer Studio and dded these files following section 2 (Stand-Alone Program Execution) of "Real-Time Workshop Embedded Coder User's Guide". 
The compiled program is executed, but it does not work correctly when I associate rt_OneStep() with a C6748 real-time clock or C6748 interrupt service routine for making the generated code "real-time".

Comment: Hm, again, I haven't played with the C67xx so I might be off base, but for the C64xx the DSP BIOS is the best way to go about making real time applications. If you can generate code and run it successfully though then clearly your design flow works. Sounds like you need to consult Mathworks to see if they support the OMAPL138...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code generation for *OMAP-L138 EVM* and *C6748 EVM* is not supported for older versions than Matlab **2011a**.

For the release **2011a**, the setup process is not trivial and it is not well documented. But Matlab has a patch for this version supports and works with certain specific requirements.

The release **2011b** has improvements (hyperlinks required for products of thirds work with CCStudio v4 for this processor) and supports code generation for *OMAP-L138 EVM* and *C6748 EVM*.

For the release **2012a**, Matlab has considered adding specific sections in the documentation for configuration and automatic code generation with these processors.